# How do I fix comment showing on code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to download jQuery into my document via my JavaScript file. When I do *document.write*, however, the "https:`//`" is marked as a comment.

```
function downloadjQuery() {
    document.open();
    document.write("<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>");
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: you should learn about basic [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) before doing advanced programming in any language. These are the basic core knowledge that any programmer should have.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but it is not helpful. Programming does not come in spesific stages that you have to learn, plus, this is not advanced programming.

Comment: The one I mentioned is a basic programming definition you should learn. And yes programming comes in various stages you cannot go to advanced programming just like that and what you are trying to do with javascript is definitely a mid-level, you just don't start coding by writing a script to download files by javascript directly. I am just giving you some advice if you have a strong basic foundation it will be very helpful in the long run because programming is just putting that basic thing and making a complex structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quote use is incorrect. You closed the quotes before the link.

Instead of:

```js
document.write("<script src="link"></script>");
```

You should do:

```js
document.write("<script src='link'></script>");
```

When you have to use quotes multiple times, you can also use `'` instead of `"` four times.
Also, if you want to keep the raw version of the comment, you can type `\` before `//`.

Example:

> (Correct Usage)
>
> ```js
> \//I printed a raw version of a comment.
> ```

> (Incorrect Usage)
>
> ```js
> //I did not print a raw version of a comment.
> ```

Answer (score 5):

In your code, you use four same quotes in the string, so JavaScript thinks your string ends there:

```js
"<script src="
```

I recommend you to use `'` instead of double quotes, or you can use `\'` or `\"`, also you can use `` ` `` ([Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)). Some examples:

```js
let Hello = "How 'are' you?"
let World = "How \"you\" did this?"
let Search = 'Searching for \'free mincraft 2022\'...'
let User = `
Hey "there", 'somewhere else'!
`
```

So try this out:

```js
function downloadjQuery() {
    document.open();
    document.write("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>");
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Great update @NNL993.

Answer (score 1):

You're using double quotes and single quotes wrong.

You can try to escape double quotes with `\"`or use single quotes `'`.

This line is wrong:

`"<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"`

It gets read as `"<script src="` `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js` `"></script>"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
function downloadjQuery() {
    document.open();
    document.write('<script src="https:\//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>');
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to describe what change you've made rather than "Please try this" which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
<button onclick="myfx()">Download</button>

<script>
    function downloadjQuery(){
        var jQs = document.createElement("script");
        jQs.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(jQs);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is unrelated to my issue. Please read carefully, try fixing the code instead of making another one and please describe your changes.

Comment: @iVers I just bypassed the "//" instead of using "//" I passed the URL as a string, I haven't created a new one, I did what you want but in another way, also if you see the answer posted by NNL993, you can be done it by using "\" in front of "//" but the reason why I haven't used that was you used 2 double quotes inside each other "nested".

anyways we all want to help each other so :)